# InvalidKeyException Error parsing public key java flutter

Tags: java, flutter, dart, encryption, rsa

Am trying to encrypt messages using RSA Encryption from my flutter app. So I used flutter pointycastle package to generate RSA Public and Private Key Pairs and then am trying to use rsa encryption in java to encrypt and decrypt the message using the key pairs gotten from flutter ponitycastle. This is my error that i got.

```
D/OpenSSLLib(16468): OpensslErr:Module:6(102:); file:external/boringssl/src/crypto/evp/evp_asn1.c ;Line:110;Function:EVP_parse_public_key
W/System.err(16468): java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLX509CertificateFactory$ParsingException: Error parsing public key
W/System.err(16468):    at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLKey.getPublicKey(OpenSSLKey.java:281)
W/System.err(16468):    at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLRSAKeyFactory.engineGeneratePublic(OpenSSLRSAKeyFactory.java:54)
W/System.err(16468):    at java.security.KeyFactory.generatePublic(KeyFactory.java:361)
W/System.err(16468):    at com.example.rsa.RSAUtil.getPublicKey(RSAUtil.java:19)
W/System.err(16468):    at com.example.rsa.RSAUtil.encrypt(RSAUtil.java:48)
W/System.err(16468):    at com.example.rsa.MainActivity.lambda$configureFlutterEngine$0(MainActivity.java:34)
W/System.err(16468):    at com.example.rsa.-$$Lambda$MainActivity$83_j9v8T2k08fC4NjzAGyU_uVK0.onMethodCall(Unknown Source:0)
W/System.err(16468):    at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:233)
W/System.err(16468):    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.handleMessageFromDart(DartMessenger.java:85)
W/System.err(16468):    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI.handlePlatformMessage(FlutterJNI.java:818)
W/System.err(16468):    at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
W/System.err(16468):    at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:326)
W/System.err(16468):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:160)
W/System.err(16468):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6819)
W/System.err(16468):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
W/System.err(16468):    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:497)
W/System.err(16468):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:912)
W/System.err(16468): Caused by: com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLX509CertificateFactory$ParsingException: Error parsing public key
W/System.err(16468):    at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.EVP_parse_public_key(Native Method)
```

**JAVA CODE** 
my java code used was gotten from this link: [RSA java encryption](https://www.devglan.com/java8/rsa-encryption-decryption-java)
**FLUTTER CODE** 
While my flutter code to generate the keys is from here: [Asymmetric Key Generation in Flutter](https://github.com/Vanethos/flutter_rsa_generator_example/blob/master/lib/utils/rsa_key_helper.dart)
This is my flutter side

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:rsa/encrypt/rsa.dart';

Future<String> methodC(String channel,
    {String priv, String pub, String msg}) async {
  dynamic _message;
  try {
    dynamic result = await MethodChannel("com.example.rsa/callback")
        .invokeMethod("encryptMsg", <String, dynamic>{
      "priv": RSA().removePemHeaderAndFooter(priv),
      "pub": RSA().removePemHeaderAndFooter(pub),
      "msg": msg
    });
    _message = result;
  } on PlatformException catch (e) {
    _message = e.message.toString();
  } catch (e) {
    _message = e.message.toString();
  }
  print(_message);
  return _message;
}
```

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:rsa/constant.dart';
import 'package:rsa/encrypt/rsa.dart';
import 'package:pointycastle/api.dart' as crypto;

class RSAHome extends StatefulWidget {
  const RSAHome({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _RSAHomeState createState() => _RSAHomeState();
}

class _RSAHomeState extends State<RSAHome> {
  Future<String> futureText;

  /// Future to hold the reference to the KeyPair generated with PointyCastle
  /// in order to extract the [crypto.PrivateKey] and [crypto.PublicKey]
  Future<crypto.AsymmetricKeyPair<crypto.PublicKey, crypto.PrivateKey>>
      futureKeyPair;

  /// The current [crypto.AsymmetricKeyPair]
  crypto.AsymmetricKeyPair keyPair;

  /// With the helper [RsaKeyHelper] this method generates a
  /// new [crypto.AsymmetricKeyPair<crypto.PublicKey, crypto.PrivateKey>
  Future<crypto.AsymmetricKeyPair<crypto.PublicKey, crypto.PrivateKey>>
      getKeyPair() {
    var keyHelper = RSA();
    return keyHelper.computeRSAKeyPair(keyHelper.getSecureRandom());
  }

  /// GlobalKey to be used when showing the [Snackbar] for the successful
  /// copy of the Key
  final key = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  /// Text Editing Controller to retrieve the text to sign
  TextEditingController _controller = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
      key: key,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Get Key"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: <Widget>[
              MaterialButton(
                color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
                child: Text(
                  "Generate new Key Pair",
                ),
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    // If there are any pemString being shown, then show an empty message
                    futureText = Future.value("");
                    // Generate a new keypair
                    futureKeyPair = getKeyPair();
                  });
                },
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: FutureBuilder<
                        crypto.AsymmetricKeyPair<crypto.PublicKey,
                            crypto.PrivateKey>>(
                    future: futureKeyPair,
                    builder: (context, snapshot) {
                      if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                        // if we are waiting for a future to be completed, show a progress indicator
                        return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                      } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
                        // Else, store the new keypair in this state and sbow two buttons
                        this.keyPair = snapshot.data;
                        return ListView(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            MaterialButton(
                              color: Colors.red,
                              child: Text(
                                "Get Private Key",
                              ),
                              onPressed: () {
                                setState(() {
                                  // With the stored keypair, encode the private key to
                                  // PKCS1 and show it
                                  futureText = Future.value(RSA()
                                      .encodePrivateKeyToPemPKCS1(
                                          keyPair.privateKey));
                                });
                              },
                            ),
                            MaterialButton(
                              color: Colors.green,
                              child: Text("Get Public Key"),
                              onPressed: () {
                                setState(() {
                                  // With the stored keypair, encode the public key to
                                  // PKCS1 and show it
                                  futureText = Future.value(RSA()
                                      .encodePublicKeyToPemPKCS1(
                                          keyPair.publicKey));
                                });
                              },
                            ),
                            TextField(
                              decoration:
                                  InputDecoration(hintText: "Text to Sign"),
                              controller: _controller,
                            ),
                            MaterialButton(
                              color: Colors.red,
                              child: Text(
                                "Sign Text",
                              ),
                              onPressed: () {
                                setState(() {
                                  futureText = Future.value(RSA().sign(
                                      _controller.text, keyPair.privateKey));
                                });
                              },
                            ),
                            MaterialButton(
                              color: Colors.red,
                              child: Text(
                                "Encrypt",
                              ),
                              onPressed: () async {
                                futureText = methodC("encryptMsg",
                                    priv: await futureText,
                                    pub: await futureText,
                                    msg: _controller.text);
                                setState(() {});
                              },
                            ),
                            MaterialButton(
                              color: Colors.red,
                              child: Text(
                                "Decrypt",
                              ),
                              onPressed: () {
                                setState(() {
                                  setState(() async {
                                    futureText = Future.value(methodC(
                                        "decryptMsg",
                                        priv: await futureText,
                                        pub: await futureText,
                                        msg: _controller.text));
                                  });
                                });
                              },
                            ),
                          ],
                        );
                      } else {
                        return Container();
                      }
                    }),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: Card(
                  child: Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                    margin: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                    child: FutureBuilder(
                        future: futureText,
                        builder: (context, snapshot) {
                          if (snapshot.hasData) {
                            return SingleChildScrollView(
                              // the inkwell is used to register the taps
                              // in order to be able to copy the text
                              child: InkWell(
                                  onTap: () {
                                    // Copies the data to the keyboard
                                    Clipboard.setData(
                                        new ClipboardData(text: snapshot.data));
                                    key.currentState.showSnackBar(new SnackBar(
                                      content: new Text("Copied to Clipboard"),
                                    ));
                                  },
                                  child: Text(snapshot.data)),
                            );
                          } else {
                            return Center(
                              child: Text("Your keys will appear here"),
                            );
                          }
                        }),
                  ),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ));
  }
}
```

AND MY Java side

```
package com.example.rsa;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity;
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel;
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity;
import java.util.Base64;
import javax.crypto.BadPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException;
import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;
import java.security.*;
import java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException;
import java.security.spec.PKCS8EncodedKeySpec;
import java.security.spec.X509EncodedKeySpec;

public class MainActivity extends FlutterActivity {
    private static final String CHANNEL_NAME_CALL = "com.example.rsa/callback";
    @Override
    public void configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull FlutterEngine flutterEngine) {
        super.configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine);
        new MethodChannel(flutterEngine.getDartExecutor().getBinaryMessenger(), CHANNEL_NAME_CALL)
                .setMethodCallHandler(
                        (call, result) -> {
                            RSAUtil rsa = new RSAUtil();
                            String pubKey = call.argument("pub");
                            String privKey = call.argument("priv");
                            String msg = call.argument("msg");


                            if(call.method.equals("encryptMsg")) {
                                try {
                                    String encryptedString = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(rsa.encrypt(msg, pubKey));
                                    result.success(encryptedString);
                                }catch(BadPaddingException bad){
                                    result.error("Catch BadPaddingException", "BadPaddingException error", null);
                                }
                                catch(IllegalBlockSizeException bad){
                                    result.error("Catch IllegalBlockSizeException", "IllegalBlockSizeException error", null);
                                }
                                catch(InvalidKeyException bad){
                                    result.error("Catch InvalidKeyException", "InvalidKeyException error", null);
                                }
                                catch(NoSuchPaddingException bad){
                                    result.error("Catch NoSuchPaddingException", "NoSuchPaddingException error", null);
                                }
                                catch(NoSuchAlgorithmException bad){
                                    result.error("Catch NoSuchAlgorithmException", "NoSuchAlgorithmException error", null);
                                }
                            }
                            else if(call.method.equals("decryptMsg")) {
//                                String decryptedString = rsa.decrypt(encryptedString, privateKey);
                                result.success(pubKey);
                            }
                            result.notImplemented();
                            return;
                        }
                );
    }
}
```

Please help me out guys and if there is something you want me to add you can ask me to provide. Please

Comment: I don't think this whole code is needed to reproduce the problem. Please post an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)  and focus on the actual issue.

Comment: @Topaco the remaining code is in the link, it's too long that's why i didn't post it